# Install VS 2008 Prof

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have installed VisualStudio Express C# in my box. Now I going to install VS Prof. Not sure if I have to uninstall VS Express first or I can have both running in my box.

I think there is difference between two. The express version does not support some sln options such as virtual folder for a group of projects. Therefore, I prefer to keep both. Any suggestions on this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can run on the same box without issue.  Just install as per normal.

And yes, there are differences between the two.

[Visual Studio Editions table.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(VS.80).aspx)